# redirect url from Domain A to another but applications exist on Domain A only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have requirement on OHS server(apache) to redirect all requests from domain A to domain B but the pages needs to be rendered from domain A only. Below configuration doesn't seems to work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://portal.mycompany.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newportal.mycompany.com:85/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this way your domain A is sending a redirect to user browser, so the page is going to be provided from domain B.

If you have to make domain A providing pages from domain B, but user do not have to see domain B, you may check `Proxy` and/or `ProxyPass` rule from `mod_proxy`.

One more thing, if you proxy domain B thru domain A, you may have to rewrite inpage links, so take a look at `ProxyHTMLEnable` and `ProxyHTMLURLMap`

Answer (score 0):

For domain redirects could you simply point your new domain B to A using either CNAME or A records in the domain registrar?

Comment: Actually, I need to mask portal.mycompany.com with newportal.mycompany.com since there are some pages which needs to be served in domain portal.mycompany.com

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues. You can't do a 301 redirect and expect to stay on Domain A. One way you might be able to get this to work is the use of `mod_proxy` and the `P` flag. Also the `http_host` variable only matches the hostname.

You need to make sure `mod_proxy` is enabled and you can try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.mycompany.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newportal.mycompany.com:85/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dot (.) is a special character in the RewriteCond pattern,  Escape it using a backslash

Try this

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.portal\.mycompany\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://newportal.mycompany.com:85/$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried the below but it still didn't worked. RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://portal.mycompany\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newportal.mycompany:85/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @User2961454 Did you add RewriteBase / to your .htaccess?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.portal\.mycompany\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://newportal.mycompany.com:85/$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L

Comment: it was working partially after commenting ReWriteBase. Now all requests for [link](portal.mycompany.com) is redirecting to [link](newportal.mycompany.com). But after redirection it is appending with one more /(like this http://newportal.mycompany.com//). And when I access any page deployed in portal.mycompany.com with in newportal.mycompany.com it is going to 404 Not Found. RewriteEngine on
# RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.mycompany\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://newportal.mycompany.com:85/$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L

Comment: @User2961454 if you are still getting redirected to 404, remove the first rewrite condition **<=RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.....$ [NC]=>**

Comment: Thnaks! I tried your suggestions. But now it is looking for pages which are deployed in old domain on new domain and i am getting 404. This is how it is looking like  RewriteEngine on
# RewriteBase /
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.portal\.mycompany\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://newportal.mycompany.com:85/$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]